# Zenity and text formating

Tags: html, zenity

I just discovered that zenity support html tags.

```
zenity --error --text "hello &lt;b&gt;world&lt;/b&gt;"
```

but how to make it work with `entry` type ?

```
zenity --entry --text "hello &lt;b&gt;world&lt;/b&gt;"
```

It's printing tags instead of interpreting them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Zenity and the `entry` option does not support the "pango" markup options.

`error`, `info`, `question`, `warning` are the only options that support these markups.

If you examine the man page for zenity - those options can have the pango markups turned on or off.

FYI  this link gives you the markups supported: http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/pango-markup-language.html

The only suggestion I can make is to make this request upstream to the [zenity developers](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with `yad`, which you can install from the Software Centre. You can run:

```
yad --title "Customised title here" --entry --text " Are you <b>really</b> sure you want to add an entry?" --width=300 --center --button="gtk-cancel:252" --button="gtk-ok:0"
```

[image: Terminal screenshot]

To make this usable we need to get any data that was inputted and check which button was pressed. This does it:

```
data=$(yad --title "Customised title here" --entry --text " Are you <b>really</b> sure you want to add an entry?" --width=300 --center --button="gtk-cancel:252" --button="gtk-ok:0");rc=$?; [[ $rc = 252 ]] && data="";echo $data
```

For help on yad type `yad --help-all` or `man yad` but I found practical examples are easier to adapt. There are some [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/yad-dialog/wiki/Examples/).

Answer (score 3):

```
zenity --text-info --html
```

can also support pango markup (as well as more advanced html). This works when zenity is compiled with webkit, and it is in all current Ubuntu versions (but it is missing after a recent update in the developing version 'Wily').

Answer (score 2):

This is fixeable by changing the file `entry.c` line 101 as: `gtk_label_set_text_with_mnemonic` to `gtk_label_set_markup`, what I don't know is why is for what purpose is set to mnemonic by default.